# SSIS - Export data from Excel to sql table

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse

When i am trying to export data from excel to sql table using ssis,the all rows are inserted . But,when i am inserting a data of length greater than 255 to excel it's giving truncation error. In output column i altered it to 500. in External column input i can't alter it. In my excel sheet there is 2808 rows..but when this error is generating its only inserting 1632 rows and whole other rows are getting truncated....
If any one knows about this,please help me..I am really stuck on this....

Thanks..

Comment: what is the size of column in table in which you are trying to insert data of size 255 char. Column size should be greater than 255. Give us more details otherwise I think you can just recreate package after making change in table and it will automatically set output column size, you just need to set input column size.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting your data by length eg longest first.
Excel import/export is very buggy in SSIS.
Sometimes the only option is to write VBA script and run it from excel itself